# How prove or disprove $f$ Non-differentiable points countably infinite

Tags: analysis

**Today,my frend ask this follow question:and I consider sometime,and I can't solve it**.

**I hope see someone can help me**

**Question:**

> let $f$ is  continuous strictly increasing function,
>
> prove or disprove :the $f$  Non-differentiable points  countably infinite？

since  the contably infinite define:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set

and I find somebook,and I found this [image]

This follow  famous example(Pringsheim) is $f$ is   continuous strictly increasing function,and there exsit a point not differentiable
$$\begin{cases}
x(1+\dfrac{1}{3}\sin{(\ln{x^2})}&x\neq 0\\
0&x=0
\end{cases}$$

we can show $f$ is strictly increaing and continuous on $R$,but $x=0$,$f$ is not differentable.

But My question:

there exsit $f$ such strictly increaing and continuou,but have  infinite point not differentable?

I can't have coumexample,Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this [*Essay on non-differentiability points of monotone functions*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/8vp1XK0-KNg), by Dave L Renfro, for a wealth of excellent information on the topic.

In particular, Renfro mentions that if $f$ is monotone, then the set of points where $f'(x)$ does not exist has Lebesgue measure zero, and this is sharp even if $f$ is continuous, in the sense that for any set $E\subseteq[a,b]$ having measure zero there is a strictly increasing continuous function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ with $f'(x)=+\infty$ at all $x$ in $E$.

The example he refers to, from A. M. Bruckner,  J. B. Bruckner, and B. S. Thomson, **Real analysis** (downloadable [here](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/Free-Downloads.php)), appears as Theorem 7.9 in page 460 in their current edition. Here is a brief sketch: Let $E$ be a set of measure zero, and (for $n=1,2,\dots$) let $G_n$ be open sets covering $E$ with measure $\lambda(G_n)<1/2^n$. If $g_n(x)=\lambda(G_n\cap[a,x])$, then $g_n$ is nondecreasing, continuous, and $0\le g_n\le 1/2^n$. Now let 
 $$ g(x) =\sum_n g_n(x), $$
so $g$ is increasing, $0\le g\le 1$, and $g$ is continuous (by the $M$-test). If $f(x)=g(x)+x$, then $f$ is strictly increasing. Also, at any point of $E$, $f'(x)=\infty$ since $g'(x)=\infty$, because $g_n'(x)=1$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

The [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) has uncountably many points of nondifferentiability. By adding $x$, you get it to be strictly increasing.

Comment: No,I remember cantor function  differentiability everywhere point.and you link can't open,Thank you

Comment: It is nondifferentiable at uncountably many points of the Cantor set. The link opens for me. Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: @chinamath An excellent reference on the function is [*The Cantor function*](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/oleg_zaboronski/analysisiii/cantor.pdf), by Dovgoshey, Martio Ryazanov, and Vuorinen, Expo. Math., **24**, (2006), 1-37. As user72694 indicates, the function has uncountably many points of nondifferentiability. (Much stronger properties than just nondifferentiability are discussed in the paper, see particularly section 8.)