# $f$ continuous, monotone, what do we know about differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am interested in knowing what we can say in general about when a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable.

To my mind, there are various ways a continuous function can fail to be differentiable. It could have a corner (i.e. its left-derivative is not equal to its right-derivative, but both exist). It could oscillate wildly, like $x\sin \dfrac{1}{x}$ at $x=0$. I'm not really sure if there are other options.

For instance, suppose we eliminate the oscillation by saying that $f$ is monotone on $[a,b]$. Can we then say for instance that its left-derivative exists almost everywhere?

Comment: Another option is that the slopes of the secant lines approach infinity, as is the case for $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

A monotone function is differentiable almost everywhere according to a theorem of Lebesgue. See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507044915/https://web.boun.edu.tr/fatih.ecevit/Math480SamplePresentation.pdf) for an elementary proof.

Comment: Thanks! Are there more general results about continuous functions, if we look at say, only the left derivative existing?

Comment: @EricAuld The [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is continuous but has no one-sided derivative anywhere. However, if we assume the stronger property of [absolute continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity), then the derivative (ordinary) exists almost everywhere.

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting an intuitive understanding of this proof. I can talk myself through the argument and understand that it works, but I'm not really feeling it. Do you have any tips?

Comment: A followup question would be whether the function can fail to be differentiable uncountably often.

Comment: @Solomonoff's Secret: Such a function can fail to be differentiable *continuum many times* in every nonempty open interval, and even worse. In fact, "most" (in the Baire category sense) strictly increasing continuous functions have even worse behavior --- their continuity sets are first (Baire) category sets (i.e. meager sets). For more than you probably want to know, see [Singular continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667939/singular-continuous-functions).