# I have a conjecture on local max/min , can any of you propose a contradiction?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, conjectures

If $f$ is a non-piecewise function defined continuous on an interval $I$, and within that interval $I$, there exists a value $x$, such that $f`(x)$ (derivative of $f$) does not exist , then at that value $x$, is a local $\max/\min$ value.

Comment: False. See cantor step function.

Comment: Or the examples in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719644/are-continuous-functions-monotonic-for-very-small-ranges) question.

Comment: so if i changed the original question to non-piecewise functions

Comment: If $|x|$ is allowed, then all of these piecewise functions can be constructed from that.

Comment: thank you all very much for your insights i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised no one has said $$f(x)=\sqrt[3] x$$ The derivative at $x=0$ is undefined (or $\infty$ if you like) but that is not an extremum of the function.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.

Consider $$\begin{cases}
f(x) = 1-x & \text{if } 0\le x< 1\\
f(1) = 0& \\
f(x) = \frac 12(1-x) & \text{if } 1< x\le 2\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

False. Consider, for example,

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^3 & \text{ if } x<0 \\ x & \text{ if } x \ge 0\end{cases}.$$

Then $f$ is not differentiable at $0$, but $f$ is strictly increasing around $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Very not true. For example:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x&\text{ if } x\leq 0\\ 2x&\text{ if } x\geq0\end{cases}$$ on $I=[-1,1]$.