# Finding a continuous non-monotonic functions

Tags: continuity

First, I would like to find a function $f:\left[ 0,1 \right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is continuous but not monotonic in any interval. Secondly, I want to find a, continuous yet not monotonic in any interval, function $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $.

Since a function is not continuous in any interval $\leftrightarrow$ the function is not continuous in any interval with rational edges, I thought about finding a function similar to dirichlet function, but couldn't find one that would suit me. Any suggestions? Or maybe I'm looking for the wrong "type" of functions?

Comment: Is the only difference $f$ and $g$ that $f$ has domain $[0,1]$?

Comment: See the answers here.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719644/are-continuous-functions-monotonic-for-very-small-ranges/719674#719674

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve

Answer (score 1):

If a function is monotonic on an interval it is differentiable almost everywhere on that interval, so it suffices to find a continuous nowhere differentiable function.  One such example is the [Takagi function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve).  This gives you the function $f$ you are looking for.  For the function $g$ just paste together a bunch of copies of $f$.