# Domain of a continuous functionn contains an interval on which the function is either increasing or decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous at $b$ in a domain $[c,d]$.

Then does $[c,d]$ contain an interval $[a,b]$ such that $f$ is either increasing or decreasing on $[a,b]$?

For example, $y=x$ is continuous at $1$ in $[0,2]$ and $[0,2]$ contains $[0,1]$ on which $y=x$ is increasing.

I was wondering this is true in general.

Comment: No; check out eg Brownian motion and Weierstrass functions

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/719663/27978

Answer (score -1, accepted):

no，y=C， C is constant number,y is continous