# Analysis, continuous curve, non-existence left right derivative

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

There is a well-known example of continuous (Weierstrass) function having no derivative at any point.There is also a continuous function having no left nor right derivative at any point,but I cannot find the construction.Where can I find it and how such a pathological curve is called?

Comment: I think the first answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667939/singular-continuous-functions) gives such a construction.

Comment: But by $(c)$ there:$$\text{(c)} \;\;\;\; f'(x) = 0 \;\;\; \text {for almost all} \; x \in [0,1],$$so this is not an example of the problem,and $(d),(e)$ do not give answer either.Which particular part of first answer is relevant?

Comment: Look further down, the (d) and (e) parts (Admittedly, it's not at *every* point, but only on dense subsets.): "Second, (d) implies that f has no left derivative (finite or infinite) at densely many points in [0,1] and (e) implies that f has no right derivative (finite or infinite) at densely many points."

Comment: But is there a construction of our $f$ given in $(d)$ and $(e)$ or it just says non-constructively that all but a first Baire category set of functions in the space of non-decreasing continuous functions have this property?

Comment: As far as I can see, it is non-constructive (I searched for an explicit construction, with no luck so far).

Comment: If we knew the name for our $f$,life would be easier.I think that it is not a very complicated construction,and it holds everywhere in $(0,1)$.It certainly involves Dini's derivations.

Comment: see my answer below -- an explicit construction is given in the linked paper.

Answer (score 0):

From [Derivatives](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2313749) (A. M. Bruckner and J. L. Leonard, 1966), on p.39:

> Even this last remnant of good behavior can be removed, as in
>   Besicovitch's example [6,147] which at no point has even a unilateral
>   derivative (even infinite).

[6] is in Russian, but [147] refers to E. Pepper's [On continuous functions without a derivative](https://eudml.org/doc/211687), which gives another proof of Besicovitch's result. It looks like (?) these functions are often referred to as *Besicovitch functions*.

See also Chapter 13, p.144 of [Differentiation of Real Functions](https://books.google.com/books?id=fXfEG-F2zJUC&lpg=PA167&ots=--5o8Zj5X1&dq=Besicovitch%20function&pg=PA144#v=onepage&q=Besicovitch%20function&f=false) (Andrew M. Bruckner, 1978) for some more references and a short discussion.